# How to fetch userID, tenantID and serviceURL from MSTeams?

Tags: api, postman, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I was looking into [Microsoft Graph Postman Collections](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoftgraph-postman-collections) but could not locate the tenantID, serviceURL or userID?

Is there a way to fetch userID, tenantID and serviceURL from MSTeams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answer mentions, you can get this via the "context" object, which in turn means you need to create a Teams application, and it must include a Tab. There is another similar option, which is to create a Bot for Teams, and when the user installs the bot, either 1-1, or into a channel or group chat, you get the chance to retrieve that information. You can see more about that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/subscribe-to-conversation-events?tabs=dotnet#team-members-added), including some options based on the type of bot and when you want to retrieve the information.

If it's ok to have an app, then simply go ahead with this approach. If you *really don't -want* the user to interact with an app, then you could consider the following:

1. create the application (e.g. a bot) in order to get the context you need
2. Auto-install the bot, as per [this Graph call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamsappinstallation-add?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
3. Retrieve and save the information in the [conversationUpdate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/subscribe-to-conversation-events?tabs=dotnet#team-members-added), which is fired when you bot is installed by the user / team / chat
4. Auto uninstall the app using [this Graph call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamsappinstallation-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

However, you haven't explained why you need those bits of information. That set is often used to send a proactive message from a bot, and if that's what you're trying to do, you'll need the bot anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at Get context using [Microsoft Teams javascript library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/access-teams-context#getting-context-by-using-the-microsoft-teams-javascript-library).

```
  // Call the initialize API first
  microsoftTeams.initialize();

  // Check the initial theme user chose and respect it
  microsoftTeams.getContext(function (context) {
    if (context) {
      console.log(context);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.